# Thread safe issues

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex, monitor

I have got doubt, when I call `ClassA:funcB()` from `ClassA:funcA()` - where `ClassA:funcA()` HAS monitor
and when I call `ClassA:funcB()` it's inside monitor.

Here:

```
static pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;

ClassA::funcA()
{
    monitor mp(my_mutex);
    err = funcB();
}

ClassA::funcB()
{
  ...
  stuff with NO lock etc
  ...
}
```

`ClassA:funcB()` is getting called from ONLY `funcA()`, is it thread safe?

Comment: Best of all, if funcB doesn't read/write any shared state, it's even exception safe without any external locking context

Comment: well, I should have mentioned, it DOES use shared variable. Anyways thanks Sehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. If `funcB` is **only** called from `funcA` while `funcA` has acquired the mutex, then you are thread safe.